# sorting subselect in HQL

Tags: sorting, subquery, hql

I want to sorting the HQL with subselect
like
Select new Item (item.id, item.name, (SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) from tab) as Created)
from ItemObj item
order by Created ASC

Is that possible?
because i get a "could not execute query" error message.

Comment: when the HQL will be translatet into sql it seems the table are renamed like 'col_13_0_' and i want to sort for 'Created'. So if i write '... order by col_13_0_ asc' it works. But how can i use my own alias? Maybe if i change the HQL Statement than i need to rename col_13_0_ to col_14_0_ or whatever

Comment: this query doesnìt work in SQL too